# How do you change the hover text on the Polygon tool in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

[mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw) lets you add a Polygon tool to your Mapbox map. I have that working in a ReactJS project. Now I want to change the text that appears when I hover the Polygon tool button. How do I do that?

[image: Polygon tool, when hovered]

I found [the line](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/3e2f29f0b76ec5f1fd912081bbee9ec68de9bf69/src/ui.js#L122) in the mapbox-gl-draw code that assigns this hover text to the button's title attribute. So I could fork mapbox-gl-draw, just to change that line. But I would prefer not to have to do that.

This is the part of my code where I am adding the polygon control:

```
const draw = new MapboxDraw({
  displayControlsDefault: false,
  controls: {
    polygon: true
  },
  modes,
  userProperties: true
})
```

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this?

```
document.querySelector(".mapbox-gl-draw_ctrl-draw-btn.mapbox-gl-draw_polygon").setAttribute("title", "your own tooltip")
```

Comment: That could work but it's a last resort. This is for a ReactJS project and what you're describing would be a departure from The React Way. I was hoping someone familiar with mapbox-gl-js would know of a more idiomatic solution.